# Управление микросхемами с помощью СOM-порта в Delphi

Tags: delphi, com-порт

Я хочу управлять микросхемами с помощью СOM-порта. Программа должна сделать не меньше 3 действий. Например, крутить мотор и обратно крутить и остановить.

Comment: Так в чем проблема управляйте, если хочете.

С такой постановкой вопроса , подсказать ничего не возможно, или Вы хотите что бы тут Вам разработали устройство и программную часть к устройству?

Comment: например рисунок простой микросхеми и программа в delphi или силка по теме

Comment: Нет это разработка устройства за Вас, это только за деньги.
Здесь Вам помогут, только если вы что то делаете сами и у Вас что не получается.
Да и схема простой не получится.

Comment: **Извините! СПАСИВО ЗА ИНФОРМАЦИЯ!!!**

Comment: хDDDD ПАЖАЛАСТА !

Answer (score 2):

Нужно

1. получить описание набора команд для вашей микросхемы;
2. составить требуемые команды для выбранных действий (видимо, это будут какие-то текстовые строки);
3. написать код, осуществляющий запись в выбранный порт (CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile);
4. подцепить код к интерфейсу приложения.